# Video Recording on Android Using Kivy (Python)

Tags: java, android, python, video, kivy

I am trying to record video through Kivy (http://kivy.org/#home) and am not sure what direction or libraries to use.

Currently I have the camera widget working with the code below, which gets the camera to display on the screen, but I am not sure how to get it to record and save the video file. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
class MyApp(App):
          # Function to take a screenshot
          def doscreenshot(self,*largs):
                Window.screenshot(name='screenshot%(counter)04d.jpg')

          def build(self):
                camwidget = Widget()  #Create a camera Widget
                cam = Camera()        #Get the camera
                cam=Camera(resolution=(640,480), size=(500,500))
                cam.play=True         #Start the camera
                camwidget.add_widget(cam)

                button=Button(text='screenshot',size_hint=(0.12,0.12))
                button.bind(on_press=self.doscreenshot)
                camwidget.add_widget(button)    #Add button to Camera Widget

                return camwidget

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: how did you even manage to run this code on mobile android. I've tried it but it crashes abruptly before showing anything to the screen. What i might have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kivy support only playing video / camera widget. There is nothing in the framework for encoding video and save it into a file.

Try to use directly gstreamer instead, maybe you'll have more chance.